# installing cdat-light with anacanda

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm trying to get cdat-light to use with Python (and the Anaconda package I have downloaded). The procedure of insttaling cdat-lite with Anaconda is very simple.

conda install -c https://conda.binstar.org/scitools cdat-lite

I am on CentOS (version 6.5) and have troubles with python module cdtime.so about library stuff,  when I try importing modules cdms2 and regrid2, cdtime:

ImportError: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /home/ramus/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cdtime.so)

Any help is much appreciated! I'm completely lost and have no idea how to proceed

Comment: I got the same problem and I am on CentOS 5.5. There is another channel where a newer version of cdat-lite (6.0rc2) is provided: https://anaconda.org/ajdawson/cdat-lite. Maybe you could have a try. This one failed in my case though.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that package was built against a newer version of Linux than the one you are using. You won't be able to use it. You might ask the owner of the binstar channel if they can build it against an older version of Linux, or see if you can build it yourself from their recipe.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up my comment: I've obtained Andrew Dawson's recipe (credits to him) and build cdat-lite (version 6.0rc2). Please have a try using `conda install -c https://conda.anaconda.org/guangzhi cdat-lite` and see if it works.